# How to set the time for a specific local in javascript

Tags: javascript, date, timezone, locale

i have a problem, and maybe someone can help me, i will explain...

1. i have the in javascript "var date= new date();" and its give me the local time (browser time) but i want force this data/time for a especific local... for example... Spain. i want everytime that someone enter in the page (from others country) the date need be the spanish hour.

i found some soluction but the problem is the summer time and winter time... we have offset variations because some time is +1 hours and others is +2....

someone can help me in one soluction?

thanks
jrms_pnf@hotmail.com

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this article: https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-6016329.html

Lifted straight out from that:

```
 function calcTime(city, offset) {

// create Date object for current location
d = new Date();

// convert to msec
// add local time zone offset
// get UTC time in msec
utc = d.getTime() + (d.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);

// create new Date object for different city
// using supplied offset
nd = new Date(utc + (3600000*offset));

// return time as a string
return "The local time in " + city + " is " + nd.toLocaleString();

 }
```

Call it like: `alert(calcTime('Bombay', '+5.5')); // get Bombay time`

You may need to add a bit of logic to take into account daylight saving time.

Comment: thanks, but i already checked this code, but my problem is in this case u are saying that the diference is 5hours and half... everytime, but sometime is less or more (i don't know exacly for bombay :)

how can i do this? hard code logic? for 2010? and then 2011.. bc maybe every diferent year the date that change the hour is diferent.

thanks :d

Comment: I don't know of any libraries that can work this out for you. Google returned a decent number of results for writing the logic in yourself: http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=javascript+daylight&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a